# Prove that the plucker mapping is an immersion

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

I am considering the Plücker map
\begin{align*}
 \Phi:\mathbb{G}_k(\mathbb{C}^N)&\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^{\quad k}\mathbb{C}^N)\\
 \langle z\rangle &\longmapsto\langle z_1\wedge\cdots\wedge z_k\rangle
\end{align*}

My main goal is to prove that $\Phi$ is a closed embedding. Up to now I have been able to show all of the necessary criteria apart from the claim, $\Phi$ is an immersion.

I was given the definition:

> Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic mapping between complex
>   manifolds $x\in X$ , $y\in Y$, then $f$ is called an immersion in
>   $x\in X$ $: \iff f_*(x): \mathcal{T}_x(x) \longrightarrow
> > \mathcal{T}_y(f(x))$ is injective.

However, quite frankly I am stumped on how to show this.

Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you can maybe try to do explicit computations. We have $T_P(G_k(\mathbb C^N)) \cong Hom(P, \mathbb C^N/P)$ and $\mathbb P(\wedge^k \mathbb C^n)$ is just a projective space, again at $l$ the tangent space is $Hom(l,\mathbb C^{R}/l)$ where $R = \binom{N}{k}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with differential forms? If so, you might consider differentiating the function $z_1\wedge\dots\wedge z_k$ and looking at the result mod $z_1\wedge\dots\wedge z_k$. [In general, you can think about differentiating a map $f\colon X\to\Bbb P^N$ by looking at a local lift $\tilde f\colon X\to\Bbb C^{N+1}-\{0\}$ and considering $d\tilde f\pmod{\tilde f}$.]